# What if have a algorithm that could generate a NFA of 42 states of any binary string of 2^32 length?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, computability, finite-automata, weighted-graphs

For example, if we have a true algorithm that could generate any NFA of at most 42 states from any binary string of 2^32 length. So, this algorithm can not just recognize the string but just recreate it from a NFA of 42 states.
The DFA taken from the NFA could be at most 42^2=1764 states.
So, even the DFA could generate the same binary string and can be easily programmed by anyone.
So, which is the implications of such method in cs theory?

Comment: Share your thoughts with us--what implications would you expect? By the way, welcome to the site.

Comment: That algorithm cannot exist (are you aware of that?) so it's strange to talk about implications .. all sorts of useless falsehoods could probably be derived since the premise is false. Is that what you're interested in?

Comment: @RickDecker thanks man. The implications, I refer to the utility of this kind of algorithm. So, does it is have any utility from the view of cs theory?

Comment: @harold Thanks for the answer. Why that algorithm canonot exist? I'm not aware of that. Understand my question like a possibility, because of the use of "what if". I just supposing: and if exist? What is the implications?

Comment: There are a lot more possible values that that binary string could have than there are distinct DFAs of that size. So the mapping cannot be reversible: that would violate the pigeonhole principle, ie it violates *counting* because the pigeonhole principle is a counting argument. That's bad news. To put it crudely: either the algorithm doesn't exist, or counting is wrong.

Comment: @harold cool answer! I will study this "pigeonhole principle", I never heard about it before. Thank you!

Comment: (There is one word present in the introductory sentence that seems to be missing from the (already unhelpfully long) title. And the first `any` makes the algorithm look pointless - it doesn't need input. (What's a *true* algorithm, anyway? Sequential&deterministic?))

Comment: @greybeard sorry, I think that I'm not expressing right hehe The "true algorithm" I refer to the algorithm(determionistic sequencies of steps) that generates a NFA of at most 42 states to the 2^32 bits long string. I cannot express myself because of limiting of language, in this case, I refer to myself limiting to write what I think in English, because my native language is pt-BR